# Weird Alternating Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help developing a general form for the following alternating sequence. I have been unable to find it from searching this site and other googling.

1 -1 2 -2 3 -3 4 -4...

Comment: Read [OEIS sequence A001507](https://oeis.org/A001057).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence is alternating sign, then think about plugging something like $(-1)^n$ in it, click [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%5B(1-((-1)%5En)*(2n%2B1))%2F4,%7Bn,1,10%7D%5D), for example:

$$a_n=(1-(-1)^n \cdot (2n+1))/4.$$

Answer (score 3):

A possible way to write an explicite formula is 
$$
a_n:= (-1)^{n+1} \left\lfloor \frac{n +1}{2}\right\rfloor
$$
for $n\geq 1$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule that you have to avoid writing the function with cases.  I think one of the most natural ways to write this is:

$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{n+1}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\\-\frac{n}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\end{cases}$

where we begin counting from $n=1$

Comment: $a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{n+1}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\\-\frac{n}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\end{cases}$